# Selecting one column on pandas (result from datetime.date from timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to select one column on pandas. That column is result from dt.date (from `datetime`) from timestamp data. For better understanding about this problem, here's the complete story

Here's the data

```
created_at               final_score  date
2018-09-07 03:22:10.753  63           2018-09-07
2018-09-06 11:31:10.312  17           2018-09-06
2018-09-06 02:53:40.136  79           2018-09-06
2018-09-07 00:49:07.007  61           2018-09-07
2018-09-06 12:42:41.523  64           2018-09-06
2018-09-06 08:23:32.121  56           2018-09-06
2018-09-05 13:15:16.082  58           2018-09-05
2018-09-06 06:57:19.128  39           2018-09-06
2018-09-06 09:00:56.311  60           2018-09-06
2018-09-05 23:59:22.213  42           2018-09-05
```

Here's my code

```
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
pivot_df = df.groupby(['date','score']).size().unstack(fill_value = 0).reset_index(),T
pivot_df = pivot_df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).T
pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.iloc[0]
pivot_df = pivot_df.iloc[1:]
```

Here's the result

```
date         2018-09-07 2018-09-06  2018-09-05
final_score         
17           0          1           0
39           0          1           0
42           0          0           1
56           0          1           0
58           0          0           1
60           0          1           0
61           1          0           0
63           1          0           0
64           0          1           0
79           0          1           0
```

But, I cannot filter

I'm trying two method to select one column

Here's the first try

Input

```
pivot_df['2018-09-07']
```

Output

```
  File "<ipython-input-61-4ac7906c5f54>", line 1
    pivot_df[2018-09-07]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Here's the second try

Input

```
pivot_df[2018-09-07]
```

Output

```
KeyError: '2018-09-07'
```

I don't know whats wrong in the process, so I can't query them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
df.pivot_table(index='final_score',columns='date',aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
df.columns = df1.columns.levels[1].astype(str)

  date  2018-09-05  2018-09-06  2018-09-07
final_score         
17  0.0 1.0 0.0
39  0.0 1.0 0.0
42  1.0 0.0 0.0
56  0.0 1.0 0.0
58  1.0 0.0 0.0
60  0.0 1.0 0.0
61  0.0 0.0 1.0
63  0.0 0.0 1.0
64  0.0 1.0 0.0
79  0.0 1.0 0.0

df['2018-09-05']

final_score
17    0.0
39    0.0
42    1.0
56    0.0
58    1.0
60    0.0
61    0.0
63    0.0
64    0.0
79    0.0
Name: 2018-09-05, dtype: float64
```

Comment: While this might be a different solution, it doesn't answer OP's question as to why they're getting this behaviour, and anyway your code will produce the _same_ issue.

Comment: `df_pivot.columns` give this `MultiIndex(levels=[['created_at'], [2018-09-05, 2018-09-06, 2018-09-07]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=[None, 'date'])`
I can't make it `df_pivot.columns = ['final_score', '2018-09-05', '2018-09-06', '2018-09-07']`

Comment: @NabihBawazir Check now I updated the issue with multi-index and columns issue.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes I agree, the issue is with the columns being `datetime index`. So changed my multi-index output to OP's desired solution. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with your columns being `datetime` objects, not strings. It's strange why the columns aren't a `DatetimeIndex` object (otherwise what you were doing would've worked).

You can either do:

```
pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.columns.astype(str)
```

Or,

```
pivot_df.columns = pd.DatetimeIndex(pivot_df.columns)
```

And now,

```
pivot_df['2018-09-07']

final_score
17    0
39    0
42    0
56    0
58    0
60    0
61    1
63    1
64    0
79    0
Name: 2018-09-07, dtype: object
```

Note: You will need to do the same thing even *if* you use the other answer.

Comment: waiting @sandep's editing the answer, if not this is will be the best answer